# Disable delete/insert option of rows/columns/cells in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to figure out how to disable the delete/insert options of cells/rows/columns in a workbook. Currently, I'm working with the following VBA code to disable the delete option for rows and columns. However, this still allows me to delete cells (not clear content, but the "delete" where other cells need to shift). Also, I want to also disable the insert option for rows/columns/cells. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
Dim dis As CommandBarControl
For Each dis In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=293)
    dis.Enabled = False
Next
For Each dis In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=294)
    dis.Enabled = False
Next
End Sub
```

I was trying to search for the "ID" of the delete cell and insert options so I could just replicate the above code, but I can't seem to find it. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sheet protection with VBA code like this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sh As Variant
For Each sh In Sheets
    sh.Protect AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The classical answer for *disable delete/insert option of rows/columns/cells in a workbook* is simply to protect the worksheet with a password and to define what can be done in the parameters.

This is an example, not allowing inserting columns and rows:

```
Worksheets(1).Protect AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
```